# Subview of reusable cell in collectionView have wrong size after scroll

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView for a chat page. I created an `UICollectionViewCell` subclass named `TextChatCollectionViewCell`.
I have another class that fills my collection view and specify a `CGSize` for each item (following UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and UICollectionViewDataSource protocols).

The cell frame size is correct but subviews have a wrong frame size when I scroll, probably because `dequeueReusableCell` return an instance of another cell and subviews doesn't reload, I tried to call `layoutIfNeeded()` to force the layout of subviews drawing again but it has no effect.

My xib file for my cell with constraints :

[image: Xib file for TextChatCollectionViewCell]

My code to fill and return cell :

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = self.manager.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TextChatCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? TextChatCollectionViewCell else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    self.fillCellUsingMessageUUID(cell, self.messagesUUIDs[indexPath.row]) // Hide labelDate (set height to 0 for the moment), fill UITextView etc...


    print("=================\(self.messagesUUIDs[indexPath.row])===================")
    print("Cell text : " + cell.textMessage.text)
    print("Cell frame size : " + cell.frame.size.debugDescription)
    print("UITextView frame size : " + cell.textMessage.frame.size.debugDescription)
    print("UITextView parent size : " + cell.textBackgroundView.frame.size.debugDescription)
    print("Cell content view frame size : " + cell.globalView.frame.size.debugDescription)
    print("====================================")
    return cell
}
```

My debug output :

```
=================B00C74D6-C3F1-4039-948B-0BAC59DC0D83===================

Cell text : "Ggg"
Cell frame size : (320.0, 80.0) // Expected size
UITextView frame size : (240.0, 59.5) // Wrong height
UITextView parent size : (240.0, 59.5) // Wrong height
Cell content view frame size : (320.0, 59.5) // Wrong height
====================================
=================2704FFF5-17D1-4E0E-9399-DD7EB4C60D36===================
Cell text : "Zyehdhzhdhdhzhejajeksvshdjajdjhhhjhhjjhhhhthhytgjuhjjyghjuyghhuygghuutghjutghkiygvcwqazdxcfeerggvbhtyjjnkkuilloomppolpôkkjjîîîukhgkurghhhhhgoohgosohsohdohsohsohshowlhdlhslhslhsglslydlgsotwyod [...]"
Cell frame size : (320.0, 411.5) // Expected size
UITextView frame size : (240.0, 59.5) // Wrong height
UITextView parent size : (240.0, 59.5) // Wrong height
Cell content view frame size : (320.0, 59.5) // Wrong height
```

Expected output :

```
=================B00C74D6-C3F1-4039-948B-0BAC59DC0D83===================

Cell text : "Ggg"
Cell frame size : (320.0, 80.0)
UITextView frame size : (240.0, 80.0)
UITextView parent size : (240.0, 80.0)
Cell content view frame size : (320.0, 80.0)
====================================
=================2704FFF5-17D1-4E0E-9399-DD7EB4C60D36===================
Cell text : "Zyehdhzhdhdhzhejajeksvshdjajdjhhhjhhjjhhhhthhytgjuhjjyghjuyghhuygghuutghjutghkiygvcwqazdxcfeerggvbhtyjjnkkuilloomppolpôkkjjîîîukhgkurghhhhhgoohgosohsohdohsohsohshowlhdlhslhslhsglslydlgsotwyod [...]"
Cell frame size : (320.0, 411.5) 
UITextView frame size : (240.0, 411.5) 
UITextView parent size : (240.0, 411.5)
Cell content view frame size : (320.0, 411.5)
```

Comment: have you reset anywhere your cell size based on content?

Comment: I use `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` but I didn't reset explicitly the size

Comment: try using `layoutSubviews`

Comment: Unfortunately `layoutSubviews` doesn't solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the constraint's are not getting updated before you assign new values to the cell.

Here is a small code which I hope should fix it.
`layoutIfNeeded()`

Just call this on the Cell before you assign new values to it, like

`cell.layoutIfNeeded()`

Did fix a lot of issues for me. Hope it helps you.

Comment: I already tried to call `cell.layoutIfNeeded()`, unfortunately it doesn't solved my issue, sorry.